# jquery easyui : How to make a column word wrap

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I am trying to make a column wordwrap. I am using easyui datagrid plugin.
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid7.php

Any idea how it can be done ? I tried formatter, but that did not worked

```
{field:'result', title:'Test',width:'55%',formatter:function(val,row){
    return '<span style="width: 50px;">'+val+'</span>';
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set `nowrap:false` to your datagrid